# Algorithm for hash code in C using bitwise operations

Tags: c, algorithm, hash, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

So I'm making a hash code function for this algorithm:
For each character rotated the current bit three bits left
add the value of each character,
xor the results with the current
Here's the code I have so far:

```
unsigned int hash_function(const char *k){   
    unsigned int current = 0;   
    unsigned int rot = 0;  
    int i = 0;  
    int r = 0;  
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(k); i++){  
        for(r = 0; r < 3; r++){  
            rot = ((rot & 1 (1 << 31)) >> 31 | (rot << 1);  
        }  
        rot += k[i];  
        current ^= rot;  
        rot = current;  
    }  
    return current;  
}
```

Some examples that the algorithm should give
"gimme" = 477003,
"shelter" = 41540041
However, this algorithm isn't giving me the correct results. I'm fairly certain I'm using the correct rotation operations and then I follow the algorithm as it is. I'm wondering if anybody can point me in the correct direction.
Thanks, and hopefully I formatted this question correctly

Comment: I think you meant to put `rot = ((rot & (1 << 31)) >> 31) | (rot << 1); `. But the loop is unnecessary — use `rot = ((rot & (7 << 29)) >> 29) | (rot << 3);` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to put `rot = ((rot & (1 << 31)) >> 31) | (rot << 1);`. But the loop is unnecessary — use `rot = ((rot & (7 << 29)) >> 29) | (rot << 3);` instead.

This should work:

```
unsigned int hash_function(const char *k){   
    unsigned int current = 0;   
    unsigned int rot = 0;  
    int i = 0;  
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(k); i++){  
        rot = ((rot & (7 << 29)) >> 29) | (rot << 3);  
        rot += k[i];  
        current ^= rot;  
        rot = current;  
    }  
    return current;  
}
```

Comment: No need for `int r = 0`. I'm upvoting this answer because it addresses the thing that had me curious - why did the OP use the inner loop?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realize that you could do it that way without a loop

Answer (score 0):

This was initially just a comment, but it turns out that it's the answer to your question.

On this line:

```
rot = ((rot & 1 (1 << 31)) >> 31 | (rot << 1);
```

You have an extra `1` and an extra `(`, which prevent it from compiling on gcc:

```
main.c: In function ‘hash_function’:
main.c:11:29: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
             rot = ((rot & 1 (1 << 31)) >> 31 | (rot << 1);  
                             ^
main.c:11:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
             rot = ((rot & 1 (1 << 31)) >> 31 | (rot << 1);  
                                                          ^
main.c:12:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
         }  
         ^
```

Remove those two things:

```
rot = (rot & (1 << 31)) >> 31 | (rot << 1);
```

And [it works](http://ideone.com/pulWQC).

In the future, you may want to find a compiler which can detect errors like this. I'm actually surprised that yours didn't.

Comment: It was actually a copy and paste typo I had made, I'm using a compiler that detects the errors. But anyways thanks a lot for the contribution